# Can I remotely control my Sony Alpha A6000?

Tags: apps

I just bought a Sony Alpha A6000 (ILCE-6000). In the manual there are instructions for how to download remote control apps for iOS and Android but not for Windows Phone. Is there any app compatible with the A6000 in the Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are many apps in the Store that can control the A6000.

Here are a few:

- [Remote Camera](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=b78cc8e9-4252-4671-b740-92c9d6a5d84a)
- [Scrap](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=896b0e1b-2c1a-40e4-9c55-09050e3860dc)
- [M2 Sony Camera Remote](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=acfa8cfd-453c-4c84-ae0b-f0009d1ed1b5)

Comment: No one of these apps works on the A6000 anymore...

Comment: The M2 does still work.